# Disk based message queue

Tags: message-queue, mq

For a project I am using Redis as message queue. Doing sadd() / spop() in a set.

However, the set get really big 10GB and growing, so I will need to move the things to some real MQ.

What could be suggestions? Most of the queues I checked are not disk based. They uses disk in a way similar to Redis - e.g. to survive reboot.

Kafka is probably only one that fulfill the requirements, but is still young project and documentation explains than single messages could be delivered twice.

Also found this - https://code.google.com/p/httpsqs/ , but not sure who is using it.

I am using Python, but I require to have PHP client too.
Also client must be easy to use :)

Comment: Am I right thinking you need to keep all the messages forever? If so may be you'll find rabbitmq's persistent messages and durable queues working for you.

Comment: I probably need to check it, but rabbit mq is so bloated, also written in Erlang...

Comment: Tried rabbitmq, was quite easy to get it up and running.